# Ошибка в простом SQL - запросе

Tags: запрос, sql, mysql

Имею таблицу **main_table(*idcat* , *name* , *type*)**
При выполнении запроса:

```
INSERT INTO `main_table` (idcat,name,type) VALUES (`test_id`,`privet`,1)
```

> ошибка: #1054 - Unknown column
> 'test_id' in 'field list'.

Я вообще передаю ***test_id*** как текст, а там почему-то принимает его за столбец.

Comment: Ну привет, обратные кавычки (т.н. backticks) это совсем не как текст, а наоборот. `main_table` это у вас тоже текст получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте апострафы, а не обратные ковычки для значений

```
INSERT INTO `main_table` (idcat,name,type) VALUES ('test_id','privet',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что вы использовали обратные кавычки во время вставки значений, перепутав их с обычными. Обратными кавычками обозначаются имена столбцов и таблиц, но не значения. Правильно будет сделать вот так:

```
INSERT INTO main_table(idcat,name,type) 
VALUES ('test_id','privet',1)
```